# Html5 canvas toDataUrl in facebook app gives operation insecure

Tags: facebook, html, html5-canvas

In my facebook app I am loading an image onto canvas & modifying it through javascript while saving the image when I use document.getElementById('mycanvas').toDataURL it says "Operation insecure". I have some of the answers like using "crossOrigin" but it is not working in my case as I am modifying the canvas image.Any help would be greatly appreciated.